# Cannot update comments file in React tutorial code included

Tags: reactjs

I am working on the React tutorial at: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

I cannot get the app to update comments.json file with new comments entered into the form.

I am running this on the node server code supplied by tutorial.

Here's the code from github. I followed the tutorial from the link above and my code matched this code. Both have the same errors listed below.

```
/**
 * This file provided by Facebook is for non-commercial testing and evaluation
 * purposes only. Facebook reserves all rights not expressly granted.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * FACEBOOK BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN
 * ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION
 * WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 */

var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.data;
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: comment,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    setInterval(this.loadCommentsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment, index) {
      return (
        // `key` is a React-specific concept and is not mandatory for the
        // purpose of this tutorial. if you're curious, see more here:
        // http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children
        <Comment author={comment.author} key={index}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var author = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value.trim();
    var text = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value.trim();
    if (!text || !author) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, text: text});
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.author).value = '';
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value = '';
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

React.render(
  <CommentBox url="comments.json" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I am receiving the following errors in my browser console:

```
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property e.propTypes react.min.js:13:4709
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? JSXTransformer.js:12226:42
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:6165
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:6391
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:7647
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:9524
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:11086
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:11662
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:11700
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:12661
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:12973
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:14794
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:15058
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:15206
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:16278
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:18609
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:18698
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:18758
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:20041
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:20601
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:20709
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:14197
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:14324
SyntaxError: in strict mode code, functions may be declared only at top level or immediately within another function jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:18973
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:25901
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:28272
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:278
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:2085
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:2529
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:2943
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:6186
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:8672
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:10574
TypeError: variable src redeclares argument marked.min.js:6:2513
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:2625
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:2746
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:2944
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:3083
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:3833
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:3977
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:4089
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:4310
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:5195
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:6423
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:8596
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:8688
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:9130
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:9428
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:9935
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:10064
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:10191
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:10314
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:10413
SyntaxError: test for equality (==) mistyped as assignment (=)? marked.min.js:6:10533
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property n.event.triggered jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:4813
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property c[b] jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:30988
"You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx" JSXTransformer.js:314:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property opts.target JSXTransformer.js:410:2
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property options.source JSXTransformer.js:9929:0
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property tmp.returnType JSXTransformer.js:8350:0
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property module.id JSXTransformer.js:12032:12
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property e.constructor.displayName react.min.js:13:3501
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property e.props.value react.min.js:12:27284
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property e.props.checked react.min.js:12:27380
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this.props.children react.min.js:13:23727
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property this._localEventListeners react.min.js:12:27772
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property a.nodeType jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2:30361
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property k.headers jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:10213
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property a.username jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:14346
syntax error comments.json:1:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property a[v.status] jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:9025
syntax error comments.json:1:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property e.fromElement react.min.js:16:9277
syntax error comments.json:1:1
vReferenceError: reference to undefined property n._dispatchListeners react.min.js:12:22079
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property n[e] react.min.js:12:18466
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property e.props.onChange react.min.js:12:27508
syntax error comments.json:1:1
ReferenceError: reference to undefined property n.ajaxSettings.traditional jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4:13234
syntax error comments.json:1:1
syntax error comments.json:1:1
syntax error comments.json:1:1
syntax error comments.json:1:1
syntax error comments.json:1:1
syntax error comments.json:1:1
syntax error comments.json:1:1
```

The last repeating error is caused by the app checking json file for new comments.

Why won't this work? How can I get it to work?
I have the exact same results if I run the code supplied at the github site for this tutorial.

Comment: Any chance of posting the code in question where is is erroring out, instead of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was with the server.js file that I was using to run a server with Node. In the server.js file there is this code:

```
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I did not have a directory called public in the same directory as server.js. I had my HTML and JavaScript files in the same directory as the server.js file.

Code works fine now that I created the missing directory and moved files to it. Thanks for taking the time to try and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This particular example is loading comments from a server, which would only work if you have a server setup that can deliver JSON comment data.  Is this the case?  if so, does your url match what's in the example ajax call?  Sounds like you may need to step back in the tutorial process and start from the beginning, not just copy and paste the final tutorial code.   The React website has all of the step by step instructions leading you to this end result.